# Filter Get-MessageTrace log on EAC with Multiple Subjects

Tags: powershell, office365

We use an Office365 email to send emails to multiple recipients. I was told to get the sent message logs and export them into a CSV format so our team can study which messages were delivered and which ones failed. Below I have put together a PowerShell script that connects to EAC and pulls the Sent Message logs for a particular account for the past 2 days. The script is working great however, I wanted to know if there is a way to only get emails with particular subjects. For example, I could use the code below to get the logs but it only filters the list for one subject. How can I filter this using multiple subjects such subject 1, 2, and 3.

```
$Subject = "Thank you for your business"
$Messages = $null 
$Page = 1 
do 
{ 

Write-Host "Collecting Messages - Page $Page..." 
$Messages = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress "no_reply@myCompany.com" -StartDate (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) -EndDate (Get-Date)  -PageSize 5000  -Page $Page| Select Received,SenderAddress,RecipientAddress,Subject,Status

if ($myMessages -ne $null)
  {
  $myMessages | Where {$_.Subject -like $Subject} |Select-Object -Property Received, SenderAddress, RecipientAddress, Subject, Status | Export-Csv C:\Logs\Logs-$PAGE.csv -NoTypeInformation
  }
$Page++ 
$Messages += $myMessages 


} 
until ($myMessages -eq $null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the multiple subjects into your `$subject` variable to create a string array.

```
$Subject = @("Thank you for your business","hello","123","etc")
```

You can then use the `Contains` method of the array in the `Where` block like so.

```
Where {$Subject.Contains($_.Subject)}
```

This will filter the emails to only those match the subject exactly.